# R - divide into smaller data frames based on information in a column

Tags: r, string, sorting, divide

Let's say I have a tab-delimited file `fileA.txt` containing several types of information as follows:

```
X         123       78000    0        romeo 
X         78000     78004    56       juliet    
Y         78004     78005    12       mario
Y         78006     78008    21       mario   
Y         78008     78056    8        luigi 
Z         123       78000    1        peach 
Z         78000     78004    24       peach    
Z         78004     78005    4        peach
A         78006     78008    12       zelda   
A         78008     78056    14       zelda
```

I have this data frame saved to a variable as follows:

```
df <- read.table("fileA.txt",sep="\t",colClasses=c("character","numeric","numeric","numeric","character"))
colnames(df) <- c("location","start","end","value","label")
```

Let's assume that I don't know how many different strings are contained in the first column `df[,1]` and call this number `n`. I would like to automatically generate `n` new data frames, each containing the information for a single type of string. How do I go about writing a function for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you need:

```
library(plyr)
out <- llply(unique(df[,1]), function(x) subset(df, df[,1]==x))
out
```

It creates `list` where each element is `data.frame` with specific `location`.

Now you can access `data.frames` as: `out[[1]]`.

If you want to keep names:

```
names(out) <- unique(df[,1])
out$X # gives data.frame with location=='X'
```

Comment: Nice trick for keeping the names :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with split, which will return a `list` containing a `data.frame` named after each level that you've split on.

```
df <- data.frame(v = rep(1:10, 2), n = rep(letters[1:10], 2))
split(df, df$n)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't know about `split()` so this is useful information. However, `df[,1]` does not necessarily contain just the letters of the alphabet, and `length(df[,1])` is not necessarily equal to `10`, so I will go with the more general answer from user:redmode.

Comment: Neither of those things has to be true. I was just providing a reproducible example, since you didn't give us one. Just call split on your data.frame, and the second argument should be whatever you want to split on.

Comment: Sure, I just needed to validate one of the answers, that's all. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for (x in unique(df[, 1]))
  assign(paste("df", x, sep="_"), df[df[, 1] == x, ])
```

or

```
list2env(split(df, df$location), environment())
```

Comment: This is cool too with `assign()`, I can choose to remove `df[,1]` from the output by changing the last part to `df[df[,1]==x,][-1]`